# "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside of a module" error in a TypeScript file when running compiled Javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, syntax-error

I have looked everywhere for an answer to this question, but none of the other solutions have worked for me.

I get the following error:

```
D:\some\path\User.model.ts:11
import { Field, ID, InterfaceType, ObjectType } from "type-graphql";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

When I try to run me compiled typescript code.

My `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start:dist": "nodemon ./dist/app.js",
  "start:dev": "tsnd --respawn --no-notify ./src/app.ts",
  "build": "rimraf ./dist && tsc",
  "watch": "tsc -w",
  "db:setup:test": "tsnd ./src/test-utils/setup",
  "test": "npm run db:setup:test && jest"
},
```

And `tsconfig.json`:

```
"target": "ES6",
"module": "commonjs",
```

I run `npm run watch` in the one terminal and the code compiles with zero errors. But when I run `npm run start:dist` in another terminal it throws that error.

Some other posts have mentioned that you need to add `"type": "module"` to `package.json`, but when I do that it throws this error:

```
file://path/to/file/app.js:14
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {value: true});

ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

Googling this error showed some answer that mention removing `"module":"commonjs"` from the `tsconfig.json`. When I do this it just complains that I have to add `.js` to all my imports which seems like the wrong thing to do.

I am pretty lost as to what to do so any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

Here is a repo with a minimal example: https://github.com/RiaanLaubscher/Soverflow

Comment: If you could create a minimal fully contained example that might help.

Comment: @H.B. I have added a repo that you can fork with a minimal example.